# Preventing Direct Access, is it possible to spoof a php define?

Tags: php

I want to prevent direct access to my `header.php` and `footer.php` files...

I know there are a lot of questions on SO about how to prevent direct access, but none of them really explain how secure those methods are.

Things like the example below, seems like security through obscurity, because anyone could just set the `$_POST[$variable]`, to what ever they wanted.

```
if (!isset($_POST['field'])) {
  die();
}

/* AND */

if (empty($_POST)) {
  exit("Direct access not allowed");
}
```

But what about using the `define` function to prevent direct access? Is that any safer from someone setting a `define`?

Something like

```
// index.php
define("DIRECTACCESS", "NO");
include 'header.php';

// header.php
if(DIRECTACCESS == "NO")
   die('No direct access allowed');
```

Or could i even do this:

```
// index.php
$daccess = 'NO';
include 'header.php';

// header.php
if(!isset($daccess))
   die('No direct access allowed');
```

Comment: You can never fake a `define` call unless you've made insanely stupid code. Then again, if you block it using htaccess it's also completely safe (as PHP can still access it, but the user can't).

Comment: The second code block you show is fine.

Comment: The easiest way to prevent direct access to your header.php and footer.php files is to move them outside of your htdocs document root and its subdirectories

Comment: By "direct access", do you mean HTTP GET, and that you want a HTTP POST-only script?

Comment: confused by this question.. can you elaborate as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've seen something like what you're trying to do in older versions of CI: `if ( !defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`

Comment: I don't want anyone to direct access `http://mywebsite.com/header.php`

Comment: @RustyFausak: We wants to make sure his `if(DIRECTACCESS == "NO")` is secure.

Comment: @Pekka웃 What about the 3rd code block, I just added?

Comment: Defines are really the way to go, as they can't be accidentally manipulated by code, they're not affected by scope, etc. Just use a define - it's how all big projects do it

Comment: regardless of HOW that script is accessed, you'll ALWAYS be doing that `define()` and denying access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use your .htaccess file. This will prevent access from outside, but will still allow for includes:

```
<Files ~ "\.inc\.php$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Now just rename your include files .inc.php, and access from outside will not be allowed.

This saves pointless modification of your code.

Better would be to move your include files out of your document root ( `include('../includes/header.php');` ) and including them from there, automatically disallowing direct access.

Comment: did you mean `php` instead of `pho`?

Comment: I really like this answer, because it is easy to see which files can't be access by just look at the file name: `.inc.php`

Answer (score 2):

[`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is the absolute pathname of the currently executing script.

[`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is the full path and filename of the file.

```
if (realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == realpath(__FILE__)) {
    die('No direct access allowed');
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the user *can* modify the value of the `POST` field (if they choose so), and hence they can bypass the restriction. In the second example, you're the one defining the value, and the end-user cannot do anything to modify the constant, so it is (more) secure. The third example is effectively the same as the second, however, it'd make more sense to define a constant, since the value is always a constant.